# listBox1=Listbox2, WinForms still display the first one

Tags: c#, winforms, reference

I have listbox1 that is displayed by the application. In one method I create listBox2 and assign it to listBox1 by simple listBox1=listBox2. The WinForms however still display items from listBox1 however it now points (I mean the value of reference type listBox1) to listBox2. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only changing the reference to list box. However the visual tree (layout) remains the same - try to remove the first list box from its parent' `Controls` collection and add the 2nd list box to this collection.

```
var parent = listBox1.Parent;
parent.Controls.Remove(listBox1);
parent.Controls.Add(listBox2);
```

For more precise replacement, find the index of `listBox1` in the `Controls` collection.